# Azure stored procedure out value

Tags: sql, database, azure, azure-sql-database

I've been trying to assemble a stored procedure on my Azure database that when it runs the query, it returns one output value from one specific column.

The likelihood of multiple results is zero since the the table being queried has 3 columns, and the query must mach 2. Then it grabs data from another table. The key is I need the first query to output the value in order to commence the second query.

At present I have 2 procedures, I would like to have one.

Query is as such for the moment:

```
select 
    customers_catalogs_define.catalog_id 
from 
    customers_catalogs 
left outer join    
    customers_catalogs_define on customers_catalogs.catalog_id = customers_catalogs_define.catalog_id 
where 
    customers_catalogs.catalog_unique_identifier = @catalog_unique 
    AND customers_catalogs_define.customer_id = @customer_id
```

The output of course is the `catalog_id`. From that I take it into another query which I have that does the actual list retrieval. At the very least I would like to add a line that simply states `@catalog_id = output`

Thanks

Comment: Could just use <outer query> WHERE catalog_id in (select catalog_id from <inner query>)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options basically to have this work :

Since I haven't seen your second query, just make sure its querying the correct table listed below as `CUSTOMERS_CATALOGS_DEFINE`

*Using a variable as you suggested:*

```
DECLARE @CATALOG_ID INT

SET @CATALOG_ID = (
    SELECT CUSTOMERS_CATALOGS_DEFINE.CATALOG_ID 
    FROM CUSTOMERS_CATALOGS 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTOMERS_CATALOGS_DEFINE 
    ON CUSTOMERS_CATALOGS.CATALOG_ID = CUSTOMERS_CATALOGS_DEFINE.CATALOG_ID 
    WHERE CUSTOMERS_CATALOGS.CATALOG_UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER = @CATALOG_UNIQUE 
    AND CUSTOMERS_CATALOGS_DEFINE.CUSTOMER_ID = @CUSTOMER_ID )

SELECT * 
FROM CUSTOMERS_CATALOGS_DEFINE
WHERE CATALOG_ID = @CATALOG_ID
```

Second option would be to do it in one query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CUSTOMERS_CATALOGS_DEFINE
WHERE CATALOG_ID IN (
    SELECT CUSTOMERS_CATALOGS_DEFINE.CATALOG_ID 
    FROM CUSTOMERS_CATALOGS 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTOMERS_CATALOGS_DEFINE 
    ON CUSTOMERS_CATALOGS.CATALOG_ID = CUSTOMERS_CATALOGS_DEFINE.CATALOG_ID 
    WHERE CUSTOMERS_CATALOGS.CATALOG_UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER = @CATALOG_UNIQUE 
    AND CUSTOMERS_CATALOGS_DEFINE.CUSTOMER_ID = @CUSTOMER_ID
)
```

Comment: Seems like all I'm getting is a Null response back on the set @catalog_id.  At this point for my application, the best solution is to just get the catalog_id outputted for use further on.

Comment: @hatrickwah don't understand how its getting a null response when its the same query getting the id currently tbh.

Comment: thanks, I figured out where I goofed. It work nicely now. Thanks for the help.